# How to show error/warning marks in Android Studio scroll bar (like Eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I apologize in advance if it is a duplicate topic, but I did not find a direct answer in any other.

Android Studio does not display marks (on the scroll bar) by referencing error/warning/occurences in the code. Is there any way to make it show?

I have not used Android Studio for a long time and I get lost because in Eclipse this is a basic functionality. So in files with many lines of code it becomes complicated to see the locations of the code where there are errors or occurrences.

In Android Studio it looks like this:

[image]

In Eclipse like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make Android Studio behave similarly to Eclipse? If not, is there any friendlier way to see the error/warnings/occurrences marks?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: They show for me.

Comment: @TheWanderer Did you make any configuration?

Comment: Nope. It's all default.

Comment: I do not understand...
I'am using a fresh install, but not show nothing.

Comment: Maybe try a different theme? That's the only thing I changed.

Comment: You can try checking the **Inspections** tab from **Settings** -> **Editor**. The default settings should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8m73.png).

Comment: @Noterezeck Inspections is the same as yours, its checked.

Comment: @TheWanderer It worked when I changed the theme to Darcula!

But it is very strange behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the highlighting level. Inspections should be selected...

[No highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNwU3.jpg)

[highlighting now activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyb5J.jpg)

Comment: Highlighting is on (always been), but still does not display the marks.